# how to execute a javascript block code using ScriptManager in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, scriptmanager

Below code is working but when I want to add 2 js commands it doesn't. For example `"alert('hello1');alert('hello2');"`. Does anyone has any solution for this?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("alert('hello1');");
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "mesaj", sb.ToString(), true);
```

Comment: That only works in an Update Panel.  You may want to look at `ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript?view=netframework-4.8.1

Comment: The other possibility I see could be your browser disallowing multiple alerts

Comment: @KScandrett it would work outside an update panel using ScriptManager

Comment: I think so. I will check the browser's settings, because it worked with 2 console.log()

Answer (score 1):

Hum, this works for me:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("alert('hello1');alert('hello2');");
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "mesaj", sb.ToString(), true);
    }
```

And I get/see this

[image]

Comment: Probably it something about the internal server. I tried simple with console.log() two times, and worked.